Extract Text from a LED Panel Image Using OCR
I have a LED panel from which I am trying to extract text.
I applied some image processing techniques, and here is the result:

I want to convert the image to text. For this purpose, I am using the Tesseract library. I tried three different models, but none were successful.
The models 'lets' and 'letsgodigital' are presumably designed for digital fonts, but they did not work for me.
  static void tryToExtractText(string file)
  {
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("./tessdata", "eng");
    dic.Add("./lets", "lets");
    dic.Add("./letsgodigital", "letsgodigital");
    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
      using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(item.Key, item.Value, EngineMode.Default))
      {
        engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.Auto;

        using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(file))
        {
          using (var page = engine.Process(img))
          {
            string text = page.GetText();
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value + " result: \"{0}\"", text.Trim());
          }
        }
       }
      }
    }

Result:
tessdata result: "gc 240 Kg"
lets result: "82.248 159" letsgodigital
result: "82-248 169"
How can I read the text? I only need the numbers. Is there a setting where I can specify to only recognize numbers and ignore letters, or something similar?
PS: Now I tried  PaddleSharp library (Paddle OCR)
it works somehow, the output is 02'240 K9
https://github.com/sdcb/PaddleSharp/blob/master/docs/ocr.md
However, this requires several libraries, and I have serious doubts about its compatibility with mobile platforms (Xamarin.Forms).

Do you just need the numbers?  I.e. is the unit of "Kg" always going to be the same?

@James hi james, yes, Kg is always there as I know

If you need a low-effort alternative to the larger libraries like tesseract or paddle-paddle, you can perform simple pattern matching by segmenting the text then comparing to saved examples.

Comparing seems like a good idea. The company provides their customers with a P2 Android phone, which is quite slow. I am considering creating a web service if this becomes an issue. But it would be great if I could do it with tesseract
